# Double float precision convert it to hexadecimal

Tags: java, hex, double-precision

First of all sorry for my english
I'm working on converting a float to double precision (64 bits) in hexadecimal in Java, already in this topic I'll need help, useful link, so on...
I've seen in  [(Double-precision 64-bit)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture)  we say that the fraction is 56 bits while in [(IEEE 754 double-precision formats binary floating-point: binary64)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)  we say that the fraction is 52 bits!

I trying to understand because I am working on a Java project and I need to represent on 8 bytes a double like for example (0.001) in hexadecimal.

Comment: Java and most modern architectures use IEEE-754 standard

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416269/java-convert-hex-to-ieee-754-64-bit-float-double-precision?rq=1